# adding setters to java spring boot controller class

Tags: java, spring-boot, setter

I am making my put method in my controller class but I have a a lot of different attributes I want to set is there somesort of plugin i can use to fill in all my setters

```
@PutMapping(path = "{documentId}")
public ResponseEntity<Document> updateDocument(
        @PathVariable(value = "documentId") String documentId,
        @Validated @RequestBody Document documentDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Document document =  documentRepo.findById(documentId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Document not found on :: "+ documentId));

    document.setTitle(documentDetails.getTitle());

    final Document updateDocument = documentRepo.save(document);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updateDocument);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Both classes have the same property names, this spring util would save you a ton of time;

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);
```

So you'll have this instead:

```
@PutMapping(path = "{documentId}")
public ResponseEntity<Document> updateDocument(
        @PathVariable(value = "documentId") String documentId,
        @Validated @RequestBody Document documentDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Document document = documentRepo.findById(documentId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Document not found on :: " + documentId));

    BeanUtils.copyProperties(documentDetails, document);
    // You can also ignore a particular property or properties
    // BeanUtils.copyProperties(documentDetails, document, "id");   
    final Document updateDocument = documentRepo.save(document);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updateDocument);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for Lombok. Basically, you can add an annotation to your class and Lombok generates setters and other stuff for you.

Comment: yeah I'm using Lombok for my schema but I don't think I can use it in my controller class

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mapstruct to create mappings for this case.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface DocumentMapper {
    void updateDocument(@MappingTarget Document target, Document source);
}
```

and then use it in your controller.

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DocumentController {
    private final DocumentMapper documentMapper;

    @PutMapping
    public Document updateDocument(@RequestBody final Document documentDetails) {
        Document document = new Document(); // documentRepo.findById
        documentMapper.updateDocument(document, documentDetails);
        // documentRepo.save(document)
        return document;
    }
}
```